# Can I apply for a work permit while on Schengen visa?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, schengen

Sorry if this question does sound redundant, but most posts I read are about applying to work while on a Schengen visa.

But my concern is, if I were to travel to Germany under a Schengen visa and somehow receive a job offer from an employer there, would I be allowed to apply for a work visa, Blue Card and residence permit? Or would the Ausländerbehorde (or Immigration, perhaps) ask me to go back to my country first and apply for a work visa there?

Additional info: I'm from the Philippines.

Comment: Are you talking about a tourist visa?

Comment: Yes, tourist visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot apply for a work permit (which is residence permit) while being in Germany on a visitor visa.

> Citizens of the USA, Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand,
>   Switzerland, as well as EU citizens may apply for their residence
>   permit after entering the Schengen territory without a visa.
>
> **Citizens of other countries must apply and get a residence permit
>   before entering the Schengen territories for work purposes**.

[Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/working-schengen-visa/).

Comment: Thanks @Ex Patriot. Although this is disappointing and makes me really sad.

Comment: @Prasad Yadav: This isn't sad because it will save you a lot of money. Finding a job in Germany sufficient for the requirements of the BlueCard isn't as easy as you may think. All serious offers will be made from employers who support you in the process from within your home country anyways. Do it the official way and you are fine.